# Show scoreboard belowname without a value

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

In my server I have set up a scoreboard system to show a staff tag under the staffs name, however, it doesnt quite look right with "1 Staff" under our names.

Is there any way to remove the value, so it just says "Staff"?

Comment: What is your current setup like?

Comment: @Joachim what do you mean?

Comment: How are you currently showing the staff tag? Can you post your command(s)?